# Magento edit shopping cart title in header

Tags: magento

I have a Magento webshop and in my header is standing: `Shopping cart - Subtotaal` winkelwagen

I was looking for a way to edit this text. I have looked into the .php files etc. but i didn't found anything there so far. I hope someone can tell me where i can edit this text.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is as erwin_smit described it.

As an addition the fastest solution is by using the inline translation Tool under

```
System->Configuration->Developer->Inline Translation
```

After activation reload your Front-end and edit the dotted text.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably somewhere in `app/design/frontend/packagename/templatename/checkout/cart.`

If not, try to switch on the template hints on.

You can also replace text using a translate file. Place a file called `"translate.csv"` in `app/design/frontend/{packagename}/{templatename/locale/{languagecode}/`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edit this piece of code:
<?php echo $this->__('Shopping cart - ') ?><?php echo $this->__('Cart Subtotal:') ?><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>

But that wasn't working.

Comment: Which file did you try to edit? Did you try the template hints, or the translation tool?